# Обновление картинок в таблице бд mysql

Tags: php, mysql, update

ребят. В общем есть форма с кнопкой, что загружает картинку в бд. И есть условие, которое проверяет, есть ли в таблице уже такая картинка по айди, и если есть то обновляет запись, а если нет, то добавляет. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что не так в коде, на данный момент условие только добавляет запись, игнорируя обновление. Код ниже.

```
if($_FILES['Photo']['name'] !== '')
   {
       $file = $_FILES['Photo'];
       $name = $file['name'];
       $pathfile = __DIR__ .'/images/'.$name;
       
       
       if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $pathfile)){
           echo 'Ошибка загрузки файла';
       }
       
       if (isset($_FILES['Photo'])) {
          //Если это запрос на обновление, то обновляем
          if (isset($_GET['red'])) {
            $data = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "UPDATE `test` SET `Photo` = ? WHERE `ID` = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "si", $name, $_GET['red']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($data);
          } else {
            //Иначе вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
            $data = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `test` (`Photo`) VALUES (?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "s", $name);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($data);
          }
        }
        
        if (isset($_GET['red'])) {
      $data = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT `Photo` FROM `test` WHERE `ID`= ?");
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($data, "ss", $name, $_GET['red']);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($data);
    }
   }
```

Comment: всё просто: **перед** UPDATE **нет ни одной проверки о наличии картинки в БД по этому ID**

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли бы вы привести пример этой проверки пожалуйста. Я ещё только познаю PHP :) Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, вроде как она почти что есть, только ниже по коду.....почти - потому что вроде запрос есть, но проверки нет....... а то, что "познаю PHP" - ну вы книги почитайте для начала, хоть одну. Там для новичков всё есть как правило.......да и для исполнения логики на проверку - нужно поразмышлять и написать для себя алгоритм выполнения для начала.......а потом по нему написать код....вы не так делаете?

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, буду разбираться :)